# Use of a generic template class inside a non-template class

Tags: c++, templates

I will paste some code bellow to better explain my question.

So, I have this `class template` called `Piece`:

```
template <typename T>
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece();
    ~Piece();
    //...
};
```

Where the `Piece` can have two different contructors:

```
Piece<TextureMap::TileTextureID>::Piece()
    : m_texture(TextureMap::TileTextureID::INIT)
{
}

Piece<TextureMap::MeepleTextureID>::Piece()
    : m_texture(TextureMap::MeepleTextureID::BLUE)
{
}
```

Also, I have a `class Foo` which has a `bar` method where, as you can see, it passes a `Piece` by `reference`.

```
template <typename T>
class Piece;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

private:
    void bar(Piece& piece); //ERROR!!!!
    //...
};
```

**The question:**

I understand the error. I need to specify which type of the `Piece` by typing something like:

```
(Piece<TextureMap::TileTextureID>& piece);
```

or

```
(Piece<TextureMap::MeepleTextureID>& piece);
```

But the thing here, is that I want this to be generic. I don't want to specify which type of `Piece` I want to pass to the `bar` method...
Or it's a `TitleTextureID` or a `MeepleTextureID`. It can be any of these two options... But (Important) without making the Foo class also generic!

How can I achieve this?

**Error:**

```
error C2955: 'Piece' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

Comment: Make the function `bar` generic? `template <typename T> void bar(Piece<T> &piece);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just make the member function into a member function template.

```
template <typename T>
void bar(Piece<T>& piece);
```

This can be defined out of line in the way you would expect:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo::bar(Piece<T>& piece) { /* ... */ }
```